# Create custom export button tableexport

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel

i am using tableexport https://tableexport.v5.travismclarke.com/ to create an excel file from my table. it works great. But i try to create a custom button. But this did not work.

I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#btnid").click(function(e){
                       TableExport(document.getElementById("idofmytable"));

                    });
                    });
            </script>';
```

If i click nothing happens. No error will be shown.

Maybe some of you can help?

Comment: Since you are using jquery have you tried `$("#idofmytable").tableExport();`? also do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: This will just create an TableExport instance, nothing else should happen. Docs are pretty bad, would have to examine the code to get the printing method.

Comment: I see there is an `downloadHandler` method, but it uses button selector `button[" + self.storageKey + "]`, so if you create such button, you can probably do `var myInstance = $("#idofmytable").tableExport(); $('your-button').on('click', myInstance.downloadHandler);`